# 2 Day Array Input to 3D array Output JavaScript. This was asked in a Tech Screening Iterview

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, 3d, 2d

I was recently asked to solve this Algo during a tech screen interview. Wondering if anyone can help me go through this, I really want to understand this.

```
[    //input
{ skill: 'css', user: 'Bill' },
{ skill: 'javascript', user: 'Chad' },
{ skill: 'javascript', user: 'Bill' },
{ skill: 'css', user: 'Sue' },
{ skill: 'javascript', user: 'Sue' },
{ skill: 'html', user: 'Sue' }]


[   //expected output
{ skill: 'css', users: ['Bill', 'Sue'], count: 2 },
{ skill: 'javascript', users: ['Chad', 'Bill', 'Sue'], count: 3 },
{ skill: 'html', users: ['Sue'], count: 1 }]
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. Show us what you tried. The objective here is for others to help you fix **your code**

Answer (score 2):

You might `reduce` the input array into an object indexed by `skill`, incrementing the `count` in the object and pushing to the `users` array in the process:

```js
const input=[{skill:'css',user:'Bill'},{skill:'javascript',user:'Chad'},{skill:'javascript',user:'Bill'},{skill:'css',user:'Sue'},{skill:'javascript',user:'Sue'},{skill:'html',user:'Sue'}]

console.log(Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, { skill, user }) => {
    if (!a[skill]) a[skill] = { skill, users: [], count: 0 };
    a[skill].users.push(user);
    a[skill].count++;
    return a;
  }, {})
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and map the key and value as needed.

```js
var input = [{ skill: 'css', user: 'Bill' }, { skill: 'javascript', user: 'Chad' }, { skill: 'javascript', user: 'Bill' }, { skill: 'css', user: 'Sue' }, { skill: 'javascript', user: 'Sue' }, { skill: 'html', user: 'Sue' }],
    result = Array.from(
        input.reduce((m, { skill, user }) => m.set(skill, [...(m.get(skill) || []), user]), new Map),
        ([skill, users]) => ({ skill, users, count: users.length })
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is to iterate through the input data and group users by the `skill`, which results in an object where every key holds an array of respective users. For this you can use [`Array.prorotype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

After grouping is done you can iterate over the keys of the grouped object and map out the desired output with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map):

```js
const data = [{ skill: 'css', user: 'Bill' },{ skill: 'javascript', user: 'Chad' },{ skill: 'javascript', user: 'Bill' },{ skill: 'css', user: 'Sue' },{ skill: 'javascript', user: 'Sue' },{ skill: 'html', user: 'Sue' }]

const grouppedObj = data.reduce((all, {skill, user}) => {
    
    if (!all.hasOwnProperty(skill)) all[skill] = [];

    all[skill].push(user);

    return all;

}, {});

const result = Object.keys(grouppedObj).map(k => {
    return {
        skill: k,
        users: grouppedObj[k],
        count: grouppedObj[k].length
    }
});

console.log(result);
```